# Could not find artifact mule-module-json

Tags: java, maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I've been happily developing my API in AnypointStudio (Eclipse) 6.2.2 until just now I added a JSON-to-Object transformer to a flow; now when I build  `mvn clean package -U`

I get:

> Downloading: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/mule/extensions/mule-extensions/3.8.3/mule-extensions-3.8.3.pom
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 14.775 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-19T10:38:10+10:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 25M/644M
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foobar: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.foo:bar:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-json:jar:3.8.3 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-validation:jar:3.8.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.modules:mule-module-validation:jar:3.8.3: Could not find artifact org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions:pom:3.8.3 in Central (http://central.maven.org/maven2/) -> [Help 1]

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong?  Do I need an EE licence to use JSON-to-Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this.  My POM was using Mule runtime 3.8.3

```
<mule.version>3.8.3</mule.version>
```

However, there is no release of the json module that corresponds to this release.  The latest at `Mulesoft Releases` is 3.8.1:

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-json/3.8.1/

So, manually changing the version of this dependency in my POM gets around the issue:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```